# How to write lists to data. table?

Tags: r

I have lists:

```
          list[30]    list of length 30
[[1]]  character[3]    '10' '20' '30'
[[2]]  character[3]    '30' '40' '50'
[[3]]  character[3]    '60' '70' '80'
....   ...........     ..............
```

How can this be converted to data.table?

What I want to get:

```
|   f1  |
|-------|
| '10' '20' '30|
|'30' '40' '50'|
|'60' '70' '80'|
```

Updated:

```
dt <- lapply(strsplit(df, " "), function(x) as.character(p.adjust(as.numeric(x))))
```

dput():

```
list(c("10", "20", "30"), c("40", "50", "60"
), c("70", "80", "90"))
```

Comment: Does `data.table::as.data.table()` help?

Comment: no, it's still there, list

Comment: I think we will need an example with code to understand exactly what is not working for you.

Comment: @plant  updated in the question

Comment: Do you want only 1 column in output with each row as a list of 3 numbers?

Comment: @Ronak Shah yes, I want one column in which there will be a list in each new row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try :

```
val <- list(c("10", "20", "30"), c("40", "50", "60"), c("70", "80", "90")) 
result <- data.table::data.table(f1 = lapply(val, as.numeric))
result

#         f1
#1: 10,20,30
#2: 40,50,60
#3: 70,80,90

str(result)

#Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  1 variable:
# $ f1:List of 3
#  ..$ : num  10 20 30
#  ..$ : num  40 50 60
#  ..$ : num  70 80 90
# - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Comment: This is it. :) .

Comment: I have for some reason writes in the form of c(10, 20, 30), is it possible to somehow make it 10,20,30?

Comment: If you are looking in the `View` window you will see it as `c(10, 20, 30)` because that is how list of numbers are stored. You can get it in your required format but that would change the values to string. Why does it matter how the values look?

Comment: because when I write the csv format I don't see the display there

Comment: @ДмитрийЮзов In that case try with `result <- data.table::data.table(f1 = sapply(val, toString))`